# Android ListView not showing but the data from json is there

Tags: java, php, android, sql

The problem is sometimes the list is not showing, my network connection is fine.
I tried running the app several times. 1/10 runs, the list is there and i can see the data from the database. i really don't know the problem
I'm using volley to get data

```
package com.example.wackyroad.internannouncement;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String GET_URL = "http://XXX";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getAnnouncement();
    updateList();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.refresh) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void getAnnouncement() {
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                        try {
                            JSONArray data = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("announcements");

                            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put(TAG_ID, c.getString("announcement_id"));
                                map.put(TAG_TITLE,  c.getString("announcement_title"));
                                map.put(TAG_CONTENT, c.getString("announcement_content"));
                                map.put(TAG_DATE, c.getString("announcement_date"));
                                listArrayList.add(map);
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

    ) {
    };

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Getting Announcements..");
    pDialog.show();

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplication()).add(postRequest);

}

private void updateList() {
     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listArrayList,
            R.layout.activity_lv_list, new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_TITLE, TAG_CONTENT,
            TAG_DATE}, new int[]{R.id.tv_id, R.id.tv_title, R.id.tv_content, R.id.tv_date});


    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String tv_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id)).getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Announcement_Details.class);
            i.putExtra("id", tv_id);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}


}
```

I tried logging the jsonResponse and the data is actually fetched.
here's the jsondata

```
02-08 10:34:38.676    6258-6258/com.example.wackyroad.internannouncement D/JSONRESPONSE﹕ {"announcements":[{"announcement_title":"Sample Title Here","announcement_content":"Sample Content","announcement_id":"1","announcement_date":"2016-02-04"},{"announcement_title":"Sample Title","announcement_content":"Sample Content Again","announcement_id":"2","announcement_date":"2016-02-04"},{"announcement_title":"It's not working","announcement_content":"I really don't know","announcement_id":"3","announcement_date":"2016-02-08"}],"message":"Post Available!","success":1}
```

I think the problem is in the population of data in listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getAnnouncement() is asynchronous operation.
You have to call updateList() method after your request completed.

Comment: I see, so that is why some times its showing and sometimes not. Thanks mate, i didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

call updateList() after updating hashmap like

```
                          try {
                            JSONArray data = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("announcements");

                            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put(TAG_ID, c.getString("announcement_id"));
                                map.put(TAG_TITLE,  c.getString("announcement_title"));
                                map.put(TAG_CONTENT, c.getString("announcement_content"));
                                map.put(TAG_DATE, c.getString("announcement_date"));
                                listArrayList.add(map);
                            }
                            updateList();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
```